# can i acheive Method overloading by changing the return type of Method

Tags: java, methods, overloading

I am trying to achieve Method overloading by changing the return type of the second Method but it indicates an error that Method add is already described.

```
public class MethodOverloading
{
    int n1,n2,n3;
    int add(int n1,int n2)  /*method name is add passing two
                               parameters of integer type   */
    {
        return n1+n2;
    }
    void add(int n2,int n1)  /* method name is add passing 
                                  two parameters one of double                           type one of integer type the add method overloaded */
    {
        System.out.println(n2+n1);
    }   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MethodOverloading obj=new MethodOverloading();
        System.out.println("Sum is "+obj.add(4,6));
        obj.add(5, 6);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answer no, only the name and argument types are part of the method signature: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2.

Answer (score 0):

We can not overload on return type, we can only overload on three ways stipulated as NOT.

```
N --> Number
O --> Order
T --> Type
```

So on the basis of Number, Order, Type of arguments we can overload the method call.

I tend to think about it in this way when we make a function call

```
callingAFunction("A", 3.14f);
```

Then at the time of call the compiler does not know what would be outcome, it just matches the argument mentioned in the call to the method defined somewhere which has the same exact type, and the arguments in the call are in the same order as the function defined, and their count is also same. Then that corresponding function definition is invoked.

Here the first argument is String "A" and second argument is a floating literal value, so among a list of function that function definition is invoked which has only two arguments, and moreover first one is String and second one is floating type value.

Answer (score -1):

We can not overload on return type.
but we can overload on same family higher type(in terms of range) in same family.

visit this link for more details.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-in-java/